# Install CiviCRM on Drupal 10 without Composer

Tags: drupal, installation, composer

I would like to install CiviCRM on Drupal 10.
But I use a mutual hosting without Composer.

How to do ?
It's possible to install without Composer ?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You can install it on another system or a local dev environment and then copy the files and database over and follow the instructions at https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/misc/switch-servers/. But then at upgrade time you will need to do the files update on that other system and copy them over again (but the database doesn't need copying over, you'd just run those upgrades normally on the live system).

Make sure the php version matches otherwise composer will install different files than are needed for the live system.